# flexbox height or big image background

Tags: windows, height, flexbox

i actually really like this approach that is big img background, but i want it to be fluid with windows's height as well (before we scroll down to other section or div), so before reaching mobile screen, its height can always stretch and fill the whole browser screen while logo & content inside is always in the middle

i like this site, http://peterfinlan.com/, i emailed to enquire but never get any response about how to make it, i try to follow its css, but i just couldnt make my header as its, i dont really see any other flexbox css other than div.hero-content, and yes i am new to flexbox, does it have javascript or what?

can you help me?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the desired behavior and provide markup and CSS samples as to what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a div fill the site using flex box, you need to do the following:

```
<body>
    <div id="mainWrapper">
        <div id="headerWrapper">
        <!-- HEADER CONTENT HERE -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

with the following CSS

```
html, body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     height: 100%;
}

#mainWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#headerWrapper {
    flex: 1;
}
```

See an example in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6mr786zp/).

In this particular context, however, you don't necessarily need a flexbox as `#mainWrapper` already stretches over the complete site.
While flexbox is nice, don't force its usage just because it's new. Getting rid of flexbox and `#headerWrapper` wouldn't do any harm here.

Please note that I did not include any vendor prefixes here, so it may not work in all browsers as is. I recommend you use a tool like autoprefixer before you deploy your CSS.

Comment: thanks god for bringing you here! i made it!

this is why i couldnt make it full screen (my header or first div in the page), i had never thought of i need to set html and body's width and height